# Que error esta generando mi codigo en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy explorando el android studio y uno de los errores de mostrar en pantalla es este, si responde pero muestra con estos textos:

> Welcome:androidx.appcompat.widget.Appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{ecd0a83VFED..CL......150,187-570,278#7f070037
>   app.id/editTextEmail}

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.constraintlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    //Variables
    Button btnLogin;
    EditText textEmail,textPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textEmail=findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        textPassword=findViewById(R.id.editTextContraseña);
        btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);
        //Asignacion del Evento Click
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)view;
        //Boolean seleccionado= checkbox.isChecked();
        String email=textEmail.toString();
        String contrasena=textPassword.toString();

        if (!email.isEmpty() && !contrasena.isEmpty()){
            Intent intentLogin=new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
            intentLogin.putExtra("valorEmail",email);
            startActivity(intentLogin);
        }

        Log.i("APP", "Click en Login");
    }
}

HomeActivity.java

package com.example.constraintlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Declaracion de Variables
    TextView textEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String emailUser= extras.getString("valorEmail");

        textEmail=findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        textEmail.setText("Welcome: " + emailUser);
    }
}
```

El caso es que necesito que me envie por medio del comando `intentLogin.putExtra("valorEmail",email);` al `String emailUser= extras.getString("valorEmail");` y lo muestre en pantalla por medio de un `textView` el email de usuario con un Bienvenido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás accediendo mal a los datos de los `EditText` en la función `onClick`. Las variables `textEmail` y `textPassword` son los controles `EditText`, no los propios textos, con lo que no puedes hacer `textEmail.toString()` o `textPassword.toString()`. Lo que tienes que hacer es pedir al `EditText` que te retorne el contenido:

```
String email = textMail.getText().toString(); 
String contrasena = textPassword.getText().toString();
```

Con eso debería funcionar.

Cuando ejecutas: `textEmail.toString()`, lo que estás haciendo es convertir el objeto EditText en cadena, y por eso te muestra ese texto tan raro.

Comment: gracias a sido de mucha ayuda.